# Hidden philosophy in languages?

Tags: historical-linguistics, cross-linguistic, sociolinguistics, pragmatics, philosophy-of-language

The 'usual self-introduction' in English is 'I am [name]' or 'My name is [name].' The former indicates that someone's name is something they are, while the latter suggests that the name is a property of the person. In Russian, the usual introduction is 'Menya zovut,' which translates word for word as 'They call me.' This construction implies that the name exists because of others, rather than being an inherent property of the person.

I am not a Russian speaker, and I cannot verify if this explanation is accurate. And I am aware that you can introduce yourself with 'They call me' in English too, but I don't think it's used that often.

Nonetheless, there may be similar examples in other languages where certain concepts have different philosophical meanings.

My questions are:

Where can I learn more about this?

Etymological development of such concepts (like concept of names)?

Do these concepts have impact on culture or philosophy?

Comment: it's not a perfect fit (which is why I'm not submitting this as an answer), but it probably comes under or at least is related to the concept of conceptual metaphor (name as identity, name as property, name as action)

Comment: This is an onomastics (aka onomatology) question for the concept-of-names part of it. However, I don't think that the grammatical frame for asking someone their name is. In French, you say: Comment tu t'appelles? the literal translation of which is: What do you call yourself? But the **correct idiomatic translation** of which is: What's your name?

Comment: Not an answer, but the German *heißen* and its cognates in the other Germanic languages (Old English *hātan*) are relevant here.

Comment: I think you're trying to read something when there's none. A foreign learner of English might as well say "But why do English speakers say 'My name is..'?  That's not what my native language does!  There must be a deeper meaning into it, spelling out the *ownership* of a name, central to the collective psych of English speakers!"  But, in truth, it's just a common way of introducing yourself.
A better example might be "goodbye" (i.e., "God be with you"), which every English speaker uses without thought, even when they believe in multiple Gods or no God at all.